# Remove text in the center of my page

Tags: fancyhdr

Why do I still have the page number in the center of all my pages when I try to remove the `sensitive` box please?

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb} 
    \usepackage{graphicx}   
    
    %\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}     
    \usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}% CHANGED expand the header <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
    \usepackage{tabto}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{lastpage} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    % References
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{references.bib}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref} % put here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    
    \colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
    \definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
    \definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
    \colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}
    
    %HEADER <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/pops.png}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/su.png}}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[L]{HELLO}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}  % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{SENSITIVE}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    
    \titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\paragraph}
    {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
    
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      showstringspaces=false,
      commentstyle=\color{red},
      keywordstyle=\color{blue}
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If removing the page number from the center is your only concern, then you add `\fancyfoot[C]{}` to your preamble.

Alternatively, you can add `\fancyfoot{}` before setting `\fancyfoot[L]{...}` and `\fancyfoot[R]{...}` to clear all footer fields.